# How to make platform-specific changes to font_size?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using the editor Sublime Text, and I'd like font_size to be one value on Linux, and a different value on OS X.  (The same "font_size" seems to render differently on different platforms for some reason.)

Sublime Text does make platform-specific customisations possible, but not in the `Packages/User` directory.  ("[Platform-specific settings files in the Packages/User folder are ignored. This way, you can be sure a single settings file overrides all the others.](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization/settings.html#types-of-settings)")  Is there a workaround?

(This is especially annoying because `Packages/Default/Preferences (*).sublime-settings` specifies different font sizes for different platforms.  So there's a need for platform-specific font sizes, but it's impossible to change as a "user"!)